# i have a problem with passing params to a route in react native navigation. `route.params` is undefined sorry am abit new to react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Here is my homepage. and i was to navigate to the bookings page while passing a `uuid` as a param to the bookings page.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import APIKit from "../config/api/APIKit";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = React.useState(7);
  const image = require("../assets/pic1.jpg");

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      getData();
      return () => {
        setItems([]);
        setLimit(9);
      };
    }, [])
  );

  const getData = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    APIKit.get(`items/?limit=${limit}&offset=1`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setLimit(limit + 6);
        setItems([items, ...res.data.results]);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.request.response));
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ alignItems: "flex-start", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            width: "100%",
            marginTop: 5,
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            placeholder={"Enter Item Name"}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: "white",
              height: 40,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 5,
              margin: 2,
              paddingLeft: 8,
            }}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignItems: "center",
              alignSelf: "center",
              borderWidth: 1,
              width: 50,
              borderRadius: 500,
            }}
          >
            <Icon name="search" size={25} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row",
                flexWrap: "wrap",
                justifyContent: "flex-start",
              }}
            >
              {items !== []
                ? items.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                      <Card
                        key={key}
                        name={item.item_name}
                        description={item.description}
                        onHandlePress={() =>
                          navigation.navigate("payment-options", {
                            uuid: item.uuid,
                            price: item.cost,
                          })
                        }
                        image={image}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                : null}
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.9}
              onPress={getData}
              //On Click of button load more data
              style={styles.loadMoreBtn}
            >
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>Load More</Text>
              {loading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator color="white" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} />
              ) : null}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  loadMoreBtn: {
    padding: 10,
    width: 350,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#01ab9d",
    borderRadius: 4,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  btnText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

and the booking page looks like this

```
import { Text, View, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

function PaymentOptionScreen(props) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-start", margin: 20 }}>
        <Button
          title="Pay Now"
          onPress={() =>
            console.log(props.route.params)
          }
          containerStyle={styles.ButtonContainer}
          buttonStyle={{ height: 60, justifyContent: "flex-start" }}
          icon={<Icon name="cash" size={40} color="white" />}
        />
        <Button
          title="Pay on delivery"
          containerStyle={styles.ButtonContainer}
          buttonStyle={{ height: 60, justifyContent: "flex-start" }}
          icon={<Icon name="cash" size={40} color="white" />}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ButtonContainer: {
    width: 380,
  },
});

export default PaymentOptionScreen;
```

here is a snippet of the of the app.js it may help

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Drawer.Navigator
                        initialRouteName="Home"
                        drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
                    >
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Bookings" component={BookingsStackScreen}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="payment-options" component={PaymentOptionsScreenStack}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Add Item" component={AddItemStackScreen}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen}/>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesStackScreen}/>
                    </Drawer.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the props? I think you have to pass it as object {props}
If you are using navigation 5.0 . Try this

```
    const  App=({navigation, route })=>{
  const uuid = route.param;
    return (
      <View</View>
    );
  
}
```

Comment: that also gives me `undefined` and yes this is what i get when i console log props.route
```"route": Object {
    "key": "payment-options-R3Cg3NAYeGPqGOr1ahDMq",
    "name": "payment-options",
    "params": undefined,
  },
```

Comment: Are you using navigation 5.0?

Comment: am using `"react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4`